# AS3 Flash Game Menu reapear

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Im new to Flash AS3 Game programming,,,There is a problem i'm facing,,,Im trying to
create an opening interface(menu with play button),,,during game play the player gives
input through keyboard,,,,and game should jump to frame 10(to show some object) and then  reset back to frame1. Now when my game resets back to the frame 1,,,the dynamically removed
menu at the begining reapears,,,,,,
Part of my code with the problem is given below....To run the code just add some temp library object tat at frame 1 and allow access to it through as3. also add a keyframe at frame 10.

```
var keyPressed:uint;

var rightkey:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, playshot);
var timer:Timer = new Timer(3700, 1);   //create the timer
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, initializeGame);
var tmenu:tat = new tat();  //show a start menu with play button
addChild(tmenu);    //added to the stage

tmenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,controlmenu);   
function controlmenu(event:MouseEvent) { 
timer.start();
    removeChild(tmenu); //when the play button is clicked                        //button and   start the game
}

function playshot(event:KeyboardEvent):void {  //detects the keys pressed and shots   accordingly               {
    keyPressed = event.keyCode;
    if(keyPressed == Keyboard.RIGHT)
{
trace("Entering movebat function");
gotoAndStop(10);      //show a show rectangle shape at frame 10;
timer.start();


}

}

function initializeGame(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1);
}
stop();
```

Comment: Nobody is going to answer a question when it is this messy. I have tried formatting your code, but seems to have extra brackets near the bottom, maybe take a look, and clean it up so people can see whats going on. Also, not sure what the multiple commas mean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you jump to a frame that has code on it, that code will be executed again. You are likely putting your code at that first frame, so when you make it jump back there the menu adding code is run again. Put your initializing code on a frame you only hit once, or even better, use a document class and avoid skipping around the timeline altogether.